# Handling numbers near infinity (large and small)

Tags: ruby, math, infinity, largenumber

I'm trying to do this operation with `Ruby`:

```
1.2679769534809603e-175
*
792621072814943158937574954417696054502273470568077747007887743862285047941581535541498718312275086275679893343076013862361579680670972527976009279036348551929550827607601145450876014530359530008733947699274904382825445634899233107885545828612637824213482759975963581961375904743254634250508637523339809985946128242523687347261107994804323593105039052556442336528920420940313
```

I know the answer is `1.005025` (truncated to 6 decimal places), but I keep getting the above equation returning `infinity`. Why is that? I'm not going smaller than the first number, nor larger than the second number.

*So two questions*: Why is it returning infinity? And how could I get the correct answer to return?

Comment: I don't think the answer *is* `1.005025`: it's significantly larger than that. Did you mean `1.005025e+200`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to minimize precision issues, go Rational.

```
irb(main):001:0> a = 1.2679769534809603e-175.to_r
=> (4519585589664361/35644067325173400145634153169533525975728347712879374457649941546088087243817792082077443838416964060770643043543706307114755505635745609361348916560329798345718708393439569922522454626926592)
irb(main):002:0> b = 792621072814943158937574954417696054502273470568077747007887743862285047941581535541498718312275086275679893343076013862361579680670972527976009279036348551929550827607601145450876014530359530008733947699274904382825445634899233107885545828612637824213482759975963581961375904743254634250508637523339809985946128242523687347261107994804323593105039052556442336528920420940313
=> 792621072814943158937574954417696054502273470568077747007887743862285047941581535541498718312275086275679893343076013862361579680670972527976009279036348551929550827607601145450876014530359530008733947699274904382825445634899233107885545828612637824213482759975963581961375904743254634250508637523339809985946128242523687347261107994804323593105039052556442336528920420940313
irb(main):003:0> a * b
=> (3582318778758723293544808766608477208802528713781684733988516016569614012687037578637365969280014511731955915723620354805192948677648150726285518854921630223111683624006805801219885647290056974705691181872855057825408797944671825308998484595184690885834492619019604611321846034964892047367198046135813425296123973237329110031154221763204044754826429491855167243281047603348342563725684284993/35644067325173400145634153169533525975728347712879374457649941546088087243817792082077443838416964060770643043543706307114755505635745609361348916560329798345718708393439569922522454626926592)
irb(main):004:0> (a * b).to_f
=> 1.005025253172702e+200
```

Answer (score 2):

After some playing around I believe your problem comes from autopromotion of the second number to perform float arithmetic.

```
puts "Original math"
z = 1.2679769534809603e-175 * 792621072814943158937574954417696054502273470568077747007887743862285047941581535541498718312275086275679893343076013862361579680670972527976009279036348551929550827607601145450876014530359530008733947699274904382825445634899233107885545828612637824213482759975963581961375904743254634250508637523339809985946128242523687347261107994804323593105039052556442336528920420940313
puts z
```

Infinity

```
puts
puts "Save variables individually and inspect" 
x = 1.2679769534809603e-175
y = 792621072814943158937574954417696054502273470568077747007887743862285047941581535541498718312275086275679893343076013862361579680670972527976009279036348551929550827607601145450876014530359530008733947699274904382825445634899233107885545828612637824213482759975963581961375904743254634250508637523339809985946128242523687347261107994804323593105039052556442336528920420940313
puts x
```

1.2679769534809603e-175

```
puts y
```

792621072814943158937574954417696054502273470568077747007887743862285047941581535541498718312275086275679893343076013862361579680670972527976009279036348551929550827607601145450876014530359530008733947699274904382825445634899233107885545828612637824213482759975963581961375904743254634250508637523339809985946128242523687347261107994804323593105039052556442336528920420940313

```
z = x * y
puts z
```

Infinity

```
puts "What? none of the numbers was Infinity??"

puts "Or was it?? auto promoted y"
y = 792621072814943158937574954417696054502273470568077747007887743862285047941581535541498718312275086275679893343076013862361579680670972527976009279036348551929550827607601145450876014530359530008733947699274904382825445634899233107885545828612637824213482759975963581961375904743254634250508637523339809985946128242523687347261107994804323593105039052556442336528920420940313.0
puts y
```

Infinity

In most languages anything * Infinity = +- infinity